# Using fscanf for reading formatted string from file

Tags: c, file, scanf

I have a file with contents as shown below.

```
[John][Antony][Mathew] Australia
```

I need to use `fscanf` to read contents from file.

Output should be:

```
firstName = John
middleName = Antony
lastName = Mathew
Country = Australia
```

What is the format to be used in `fscanf` to get firstName, middleName, lastName and country in separate strings?

Currently `fscanf(fp, "[%[^]]",firstName)` gives firstName correctly.

Comment: `"[%[^]]][%[^]]][%[^]]] %[^\n]%*c"` , %(buffer size -1)[...]

Answer (score 1):

Akin to @BLUEPIXY comment `"[%[^]]][%[^]]][%[^]]] %[^\n]%*c"`.

Since data is certainly *per line*, read a *line* first and then parse it.

The format needed is `"[%99[^]]]"` which says to 1) scan `'['` 2) scan up to 99 non-`]` char and form a string 3) scan `']'`.

```
#define N 100
#define FMT "[%99[^]]]" 
#define FMTCTY " %99[^\n]" 
char firstName[N], middleName[N], lastName[N], Country[N];

char buf[4*N + 10];
while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp) != NULL) {
  if (4 != sscanf(buf, FMT FMT FMT FMTCTY, firstName, middleName, lastName, Country)) {
    break;
  }
  foo(firstName, middleName, lastName, Country);
}
```

Confident OP can form the needed output format string.

Answer (score 0):

```
char buf[1024];

FILE* fp = fopen("file.in", "r");
fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp);
fclose(fp);

// substitute '[' and ']' with a space

sscanf(buf, "%s%s%s%s", firstName, middleName, lastName, Country);
```

Also can be done by reading character stream and overpass all spaces, '[' and ']'.

Comment: `"%s"` will have trouble reading "New Zealand" into `Country` as scanning stops when the space is encountered.